# Condition for a system state to shrink

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, control-theory

Let's consider the following system:

$${\boldsymbol x}(t)=e^{-\boldsymbol A t}{\boldsymbol x_0}$$

Where ${\boldsymbol A}$ is a square matrix (potentially asymmetric).

What are the required and sufficient conditions on ${\boldsymbol A}$ for having $||{\boldsymbol x}(t)||$ always shrinking with time monotonically.

<del>I suspect the required and sufficient condition is that ${\boldsymbol A}$ is positive definite. But I cannot prove it.</del>

---

PS.

I cannot conclude if the system is stable, the state monotonically shrinks.

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive, positively

Comment: Hmm, you think the above is a rant?

Comment: If $A=\operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$, then $\|e^A\| > 1$ but the system is unstable.

Comment: @copper.hat, My generalization is ${\boldsymbol A}\succ \boldsymbol 0$. But, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I presume you mean $x^TAx >0$ for non zero $x$ (meaning $A$ may not be symmetric)?

Comment: I apologise, I didn't read the 'always shrinking' part.

Comment: @copper.hat, Yes, I mean positive definiteness.

Comment: I presume $A$ is real?

Comment: @copper.hat, Yes it is real.

Comment: I suspect the answer is **iff** the eigenvalues are real & positive, but haven't had a chance to check yet. Possibly multiplicity one as well?

Comment: ${\boldsymbol A}$ can have multiple similar eigenvalues too. If that's what you mean.

Comment: I think your intuition is correct, mine is out to lunch.

Comment: Is the question about a specific $x_0$ or any $x_0$? If the system response is required to shrink for any $x_0$ then the answer is **iff** $A >0$. However, a specific $x_0$ is more nuanced.

Comment: (Or really $A+A^T >0$ if positive definite means symmetric.)

Comment: @copper.hat, For any initial state. How did you reach ${\boldsymbol A}+{\boldsymbol A}^T$? I prefer asymmetric ${\boldsymbol A}$. It is my bad to mention positive definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $\phi(t) = {1 \over 2} \|x(t)\|^2$, then 
$\phi'(t) = x^T(t) x'(t) = -x^T(t) A x(t)$.

Then, the norm of the state is strictly decreasing for any non zero initial state $x_0$ 
**iff** $-x_0^T A x_0 < 0$ for all $x_0 \neq 0$.

Note that $x_0^T A x_0 > 0$ for all $x_0 \neq 0$ **iff** $x_0^T (A+A^T) x_0 > 0$ for all $x_0 \neq 0$ **iff** $A>0$.

Comment: If ${\boldsymbol A}$ is not symmetric does it contradict $-{\boldsymbol x}_0^T{\boldsymbol A}{\boldsymbol x}_0<0$ for all ${\boldsymbol x}_0\ne 0$?

Comment: Since $x^T(A+A^T)x = 2 x^T Ax$ it doesn't matter. However, it is more straightforward to check positive definiteness of a symmetric matrix (an eigenvalue check or solve the Lyapunov equation).

Comment: Very nice solution! +1